# Postgres username not found when adding Elixir app to CircleCI

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, circleci

I'm having trouble trying to get my Elixir/Phoenix app on CircleCI.
I've added their config files, tried messing with it and nothing seems to work... It says

```
** (KeyError) key :username not found in: [types: Postgrex.DefaultTypes, backoff_type: :stop, pool: DBConnection.Connection, database: "postgres", otp_app: :todo_with_auth, repo: TodoWithAuth.Repo, timeout: 15000, pool_timeout: 5000, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, hostname: "localhost", pool_size: 10]
    (elixir) lib/keyword.ex:343: Keyword.fetch!/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:548: Postgrex.Protocol.startup/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:475: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:134: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Here's the config file

```
# Elixir CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-elixir/ for more details
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version here
      - image: circleci/elixir:1.4

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout

      # specify any bash command here prefixed with `run: `
      - run: mix local.hex --force
      - run: mix local.rebar
      - run: mix deps.get
      - run: mix ecto.create
      - run: mix test
```

My test environment (test.exs)

```
config :todo_with_auth, TodoWithAuth.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "todo_with_auth_test",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
```

The dev.exs is similar to this, however the username/password lines are commented there

If you need more info:

[CircleCI Failling](https://circleci.com/gh/fskinner/todo_with_auth/9)

[Github Repo](https://github.com/fskinner/todo_with_auth)

Just let me know if you need more info to help me :)

Comment: You need to put the correct auth details here: https://github.com/fskinner/todo_with_auth/blob/3fc7d48753822b6a608fb1288844a971c704be96/config/dev.exs#L42.

Comment: I did put the auth details on test.exs... Does it need to be on dev.exs?

Comment: Ah, I believe I got it: you should explicitly `export MIX_ENV=test` and/or just prepend it to the custom line in circle’s config, dealing with the database, like `run: MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.create`.

Comment: That fixed it! I just added MIX_ENV=test on my mix tasks and it worked! Thanks :) You should add an answer with that so i can mark as correct

Comment: I thought  that CircleCI automatically added those env vars so I would never think of exporting them myself :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CircleCI does not add any environments variables for the sake of consistency of your build. Also, `mix` itself (some `mix` tasks to be precise) do this. E.g., if you’ll take a look in the very end of the generated `mix.exs` file, you’ll see something like:

```
defp aliases do
  [
    "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
    "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
    "test": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]
  ]
end
```

`Test` task adds `MIX_ENV=test` to the environment. `Ecto.Create` task, on the other hand, *does not*, since it’s to be run in all environments. That makes your database creation to be attempted in the default (`dev`) environment.

That said, adding `MIX_ENV=test` wherever applicable would fix the issue:

```
# - run: mix ecto.create
- run: MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.create
```

or, even better, you should just *remove* the line above, since there is an alias for `test` (see `mix.exs` aliases,) that implicitly *drops and silently recreates the database itself*. `mix ecto.create` is a noop, since you never call `ecto.migrate` afterward (`test` alias does it for you.)